# Adding vlookup formula to column with pandas python without looping through rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is it possible to add a VLOOKUP formula to a column with pandas python without using a  for loop to loop through each row?

This is the loop I have which works but is a bit slow on an Excel file with over 60,000 rows

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    df1.loc[i, 'OutcomeGroupCodeName'] = "=VLOOKUP(N" + str(i + 2) + ",OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)"
```

The ID to use for the vlookup is column N on each row in the Excel sheet. This is the equivalent of opening Excel and adding it to the cells i.e.

```
=VLOOKUP(N2,OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(N3,OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)
```

I know you can use pandas to join data which does the same as VLOOKUP but I need the formula in the final Excel file that pandas writes so that if the value is ever changed in the exported Excel sheet later on it will automatically apply the VLOOKUP. So applying the merge/VLOOKUP in pandas before saving to Excel won't work for me.

This will write the formula to each cell in the column but I don't know how to add the index/row number to part of the string

```
df1['OutcomeGroupCodeName'] = "=VLOOKUP(N,OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.apply` can solve this

```
df.apply(lambda row: "=VLOOKUP(N{},OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)".format(row.name), axis=1)
```

Comment: @kevinc is this what you are after?

Comment: it looks perfect, however I can't get it to work. It's giving me this error "TypeError: must be str, not int". I've used astype(str) to convert the column to string thinking that might be the problem but it hasn't solved it. I'm currently Googling for a solution

Comment: I've removed the +2 from i+2 and it ran without errors. I'm just going to run it on a small Excel file to see what it looks like when exported back into Excel

Comment: @KevinC I've changed the `i` part from `i+2` to `str(int(i)+2)`. Does this fully answer the question?

Comment: @DillonC It's closer, but I'm getting this output in Excel: =VLOOKUP(Nnan,OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE). Is this because I don't have a row index?

Comment: @KevinC I've changed the code to use `.apply()` and it used `row.name` to get the row number. Does this now work?

Comment: @DillonC, it says that float attribute has no attribute 'name'. One thing I've noticed (while it doesn't fix this problem) is that it looks like you need to set the column data back into itself i.e. `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].map(...)`. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: This works! `df1['OutcomeGroupCodeName'] = df1.apply(lambda row: '=VLOOKUP(N{},OUTCOMES!A:O,3,FALSE)'.format(row.name + 2), axis=1)` Thank you!

Comment: @KevinC Fantastic! Happy to help! Please upvote if this solved the problem

Comment: I did press the upvote button earlier on but saw a message saying that my count doesn't show because I'm new